# SSRS 2012 - tablix is repeating the first row for every row in the tablix

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

SQL Server 2012
SSRS 2012

I am using a tablix that is fed by a dataset with a stored procedure query.
I can run the procedure fine and get the results that I expect.

However, when I run the report and get the results displayed into the tablix, I get the proper number of columns and rows returned, but the results are all a repeat of the first row.

I have no column headers. Just data, but again, the first row is being repeated for every row I get back.

This was working before and I changed a number of things to address another issue I had...somewhere along the way, I introduced this; just not sure where.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Share the expressions you are using in the first row of your tablix. I think you are using the the FIRST() function.

Comment: No, not using the first function. I'll get what I am using. Thanks for the reply

Comment: This is the only function I am using (in the "action" for the report):

Comment: =iif(lookup(Parameters!PERSON_ID.Value, Fields!PERSON_ID.Value, Fields!PNM.Value, "ds_PERSONS")>1
 , iif(IsNothing(Fields!PIP1.Value)=True
  , Nothing
  , "rpt_PIVOTED")
 , Nothing)

Comment: So you are getting "rpt_PIVOTED" in every row (?). It's obvious but did you check that your data produces different results against the logic function?

Comment: Let me clarify, rpt_PIVOTED is the report that I call in the "action" for each cell of the tablix (its a long story of why I want to do this... just go with it). The report basically calls itself when someone clicks in the tablix. Depending on the cell clicked, the report (rpt_PIVOTED) is called again with varying parameters (according to the cell clicked), but the same 50 rows are returned.

Comment: The report calls a stored procedure "p_REPORT_DATA". This stored proc returns the 50 rows with all the varying values in all columns as expected when I run in SMS. But when I run the same stored procedure thru the SSRS report, I get the repeated first row of data in all 50 rows.

Comment: I worked around this by just recreating the tablix. Not sure what I wrecked. Working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by just recreating the tablix. Not sure what I wrecked. Working fine now.

Comment: I just wanted to add to this question and what worked for me.  My report was having the exact same issue and my solution was what Alejandro Zuleta mentioned about the 'First()' function.  Once I removed it from my expression in the cell of the tablix, it solved my issue.